# not being able to display the current user details using sql in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have used an sql statement where I want to display the details of the current user that is logged in. But when I run this command it

```
ConnectionString = "<%$ ConnectionStrings:Details %>" 

SelectCommand = "SELECT *  FROM member WHERE username = 'User.Identity.Name'"
```

it does not show any details but when I run

```
SelectCommand = "SELECT *  FROM member WHERE username = 'david'"
```

the username david exists in the database and displays the details of only david in the web form. I even did `Response.Write` on the `User.Identity.Name` and that statement displays the current user that is logged in the page.

Comment: it says name "David" when I run the debugger in visual studio System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity |{System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity}
name = "David"

Comment: authenticationtype = "forms"
isAuthenticated = "true"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you're passing the actual `User.Identity.Name` as string instead of its value.

```
SelectCommand = String.Format("SELECT *  FROM member WHERE username = '{0}'", User.Identity.Name)
```

But the better (and safer) practice would be something like

```
SelectCommand = "SELECT *  FROM member WHERE username = @UserName"
SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", User.Identity.Name)
```

This will prevent SQL injection.

**EDIT:**
Since you are defining this in your page, you can use the following template:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Details %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM members WHERE ([username] = @UserName)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="UserName" Type="String" DefaultValue="" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Then set the default value to `User.Identity.Name` on the server side:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Item(0).DefaultValue = User.Identity.Name
```

The easier way to do this is by using the `Configure Data Source` wizard, which is available by clicking the right arrow beside the SqlDataSource object in design view.

Comment: the statement with the SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue gives me errors and says this attribute must be followed by an equal sign and a value. If the value is in quotation mark the quotation mark must match
the first statement does not show any errors I also have <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1"
    ConnectionString = "<%$ ConnectionStrings:Details %>"

Comment: Error 3 Literal expressions like '<%$ ConnectionStrings:Details %>' are not allowed. Use <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Details%>" /> instead.  191 thats the error the above is not the error

Comment: <asp:SqlDataSource ID = "SqlDataSource1"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Details %>"
SelectCommand = "SELECT *  FROM member" it works with this statement in my program

Comment: Okay so you're defining it in your page. Please see my updated answer.